# How to make something like this in material ui react?

Tags: material-ui

How can i make this in material ui react? [image]

The main problem i have is i don't know how to make the right part with the refresh icon.

Answer (score 1):

This question is kinds an amateur question. But I can give you little insights how you can start with little basics and you can later make it stateful component.

```
const styles = theme => ({
margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  roundBorder : {
    borderRadius: '25px',
    borderColor: '#80bdff',
    border: '1px solid #ced4da',
  }
});

function App(props) {
const { classes } = props;

return (
<div>

  <div className={classes.margin}>
    <Grid container spacing={8} alignItems="flex-end">

      <Grid item>
        <TextField className={classes.roundBorder} id="input-with-icon-grid" label="With a grid" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <AccountCircle />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </div>
</div>
 );
 }
```

This will create something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample which has searching with icon, just align icon to the right:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-jhy9f